# Where to find the windows installer for anaconda version 4.6.11

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to find an install an old version of anaconda. I have been trying to find the windows 64 installer for the anaconda 4.6.11 version but didnt succeed.

Could anybody tell me where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Via link must be all previous versions installers available:
https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

conda 4.6.11 = Anaconda 2019.03

Check for yourself: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-2019-03-release

So you could use command  `conda install anaconda=2019.03`

Comment: Thanks @Neophyte, but I cant see version 4.6.11. Do you?

Comment: Aaaah, I see. Thank you very much gentlemen.

Comment: Np, unforunatelly I cannot find 2019.03 version in old repo versions installers archive but command must do the job.